# Полностью подчеркнуть многострочный текст

Tags: html, css

Делаю печатную форму, в которую динамически должны подставляться данные некоторого заявителя. Проблема заключается в том, что:

- при использовании `<u>` и `text-decoration:underline` не подчеркивается вся строка в случае, если текст меньше ширины блока
- при использовании свойства `border` и его производных подчеркивается только последняя строка

[Описанное выше на jsfillde](https://jsfiddle.net/IvvI/0dtrnpce/)

Конечно же предварительно прогуглил данную проблему, но ничего подходящего не нашел. Надеюсь, кто-то из руссообщества с таким все-таки сталкивался. Нужен максимально простой вариант с использованием html/css.

Comment: и где там (в примере) `<ul>`?

Comment: @diproart, ошибся, `<u>`  конечно же

Comment: У меня в хроме строка с `text-decoration:underline` подчёркнута полностью.

Comment: вот что народ говорит - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20916586/html-css-underline-full-width

Comment: Я уже спрашивал что-то похожее, возможно дубликат: [Разделитель между строками на всю ширину](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/747622/178213)

Comment: @Ivan Tikhonov Если ответ вам был полезен, а он был полезен судя по зелёной галке, которую вы поставили, как верное решение, то почему **вы не отметили ответ плюсом** (верхний треугольник у ответа)  Посмотрел ваш профиль, ни одного плюса вы не поставили за ответы данные вам.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, мне казалось, люди на форумах не за медальки помогают. и, кажется, вы про рейтинг забыли

Comment: @IvanTikhonov да, вы правы, но только в одном не за медальки тут люди работают. А в основном за получение знаний. Ведь отвечая на вопросы идет очень быстрый рост собственной квалификации. Рейтинг общий за галки идёт, но  повышение рейтинга по конкретной специализации, метке дают только плюсы. И не последнее место в паре - вопрошающий -отвечающий занимают чисто человеческие отношения. Бережливому пользователю, которому жалко плюс поставить за потраченное на него время и полученный ответ, в последствии и отвечать не очень хочется.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, хватит разводить демагогию, никакой логики в вашем ответе не обнаружил, про рейтинг не поняли. Не нравится - не отвечайте. Создайте вопрос об этикете общения на форуме там поучайте и спорьте.

Comment: @Ivan Tikhonov  судят о чужой логике обычно люди у которых своей маловато. Вы действительно ничего не поняли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.text{
  font-size:14px;
  line-height:1.5;
  /*высота строки будет 14px*1.5=21px По этому значению и делается градиент*/
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent 0, transparent 20px,currentColor 20px,currentColor 21px);
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, possimus, asperiores, doloremque consectetur mollitia quibusdam laudantium maxime neque repellat reprehenderit nostrum officia recusandae. Velit, adipisci, quidem, ipsa nam blanditiis sed doloribus voluptas quaerat cupiditate ipsam aliquam fugiat animi possimus nobis aperiam laudantium officia iste voluptate corrupti</div>
```

Comment: решение отсюда - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20916586/html-css-underline-full-width из 2014 года

Comment: @diproart , можно и так, но при размере шрифта больше 20px будет ая-яй. Лучше задавать параметры явно.

Comment: @diproart , если это обвинение в плагиате, то оно несостоятельно.

Comment: **Ключевая "фишка" этого решения: комбинация высоты строки и `repeating-linear-gradient`.** Остальное вариации на тему. // p.s. я ни к кому персонально не обращаюсь, просто указываю на совпадение ответов. Решение показалось оригинальным и достойным упоминания. Лишний раз...: формулируйте запросы к google на английском, и найдете много интересного). "Если, да кабы, ..." - это не разговор.

Comment: @diproart , вы не просто указали на совпадение ответов, вы написали "решение отсюда". А это не так.

Comment: Возможно. Я свою позицию объяснил. Это не умоляет ваши заслуги. Вам же известны многие истории о совпадениях. Но первые упоминания имеют приоритет. А уж для интернета это сплошь и рядом.